# Type constraints with multiple type variables in Haskell function signature

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, type-variables, function-signature

I have been searching on documentations and wikis for Haskell's type constraints in function signatures. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer.

At this time, I consider myself as a beginner, so I would like to ask your comprehension if you see misuse of technical terms or lack of advanced knowledge on this topic.

#### First scenario

Consider a real example given by the function signature below:

```hs
count :: (Eq e, Num n) => e -> [e] -> n -> n
```

This function has the type constraints: `Eq` and `Num`, each one with exactly one variable, respectively: `e` and `n`. I could have provided a simpler signature with only one constraint too (e.g. `foo :: Eq a => a -> Bool`).

But what about the following?

#### Second scenario

Consider the hypothetical examples. I thought of them trying to represent multiple variables that belong to the same type constraint.

```hs
-- As far as I tested, the examples below are incorrect
-- and do not reflect proper Haskell syntax

foo :: (Num a b c) => use the variables here

or

foo :: Num a, b, c => use the variables here
```

Can we specify more than one variable in the same constraint, like I tried above? Would I have to specify them individually?

```hs
foo :: Eq a, Eq b ... => use the variables here
```

Is there any case in which one would use multiple type variables of the same type, what impacts does this bring?

---

> Edit - May 1, 2023: I accepted Ben’s answer, for I believe it explains thoroughly and in rich details about my questions. I really found it to be clarifying and very constructive as he also complements pointing out to Joseph’s answers, which are relevant to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for constraints is that left of the `=>` arrow you must have a single thing of kind `Constraint`.

`()` is a `Constraint` (the empty one that is always satisfied and provides no capabilities). Any single type class constraint is obviously a `Constraint`. A pair of constraints is also a `Constraint`, and must be written `(c1, c2)`. Likewise triples, quadruples, etc. If you want multiple constraints, you put them in a comma-separated list surrounded by parentheses.

Basic type-class names like `Eq`, `Num`, etc are `Constraint` *producers*. They have kinds `Type -> Constraint`, i.e. you apply them to a type (most commonly a variable) to make a `Constraint`. So I can apply `Num` to the type variable `a` to make a `Constraint` like `Num a`.

But `Num a b c` doesn't make sense; it is requiring `Num` to be something that can be applied to *three* types to make a `Constraint`. Such a thing would have kind `Type -> Type -> Type -> Constraint`, and things like that **can** exist so we can't have `Num a b c` automatically apply `Num` to all 3 variables without interfering with the syntax for applying multi-paramter type classes to multiple variables.

If you want all of `a`, `b`, and `c` to have `Num` constraints, the "builtin" Haskell syntax for that is simply `(Num a, Num b, Num c)`. A little repetitive perhaps, but since type class constraints declare the *interface* you are using to work with values of types `a`, `b`, and `c` it's important information to be clear about. It's also uncommon for a Haskell function to have a *huge* number of type variables, so more than a handful of repetitions of a type class name in a signature is an extremely uncommon problem anyway.

Nevertheless, there are ways to address this if you want using more advanced Haskell. `Constraint`s (and the things that produce them, like `Num`, `Eq`, etc) are perfectly ordinary type-level entities in Haskell<sup>1</sup>, so any feature that can be used to manipulate types can be used to manipulate `Constraint`s. So even though there's no builtin syntax for applying a single constraint-producer (like `Num`) to multiple types, you can *make* something to do that job. The other answers have shown a couple of ways of doing this. If you're relatively early in your Haskell learning I'd *probably* recommend you just stick with writing out all the constraints manually for now, but up to you.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, they are with the `ConstraintKinds` language extension, but this is extremely well-accepted and now enabled by default on compilers that support the `GHC2021` language.

---

> Is there any case in which one would use multiple type variables of the same type, what impacts does this bring?

Are you talking about using multiple type variables with the type class constraint? Say like `pairEqual :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Bool`? Yes, that is sometimes done.

Each variable (and constraint) means the same thing as it always does. The caller of `pairEqual` can choose `a` to be any type they like (that has an `Eq` instance), and can choose `b` to be any type they like (that has an `Eq` instance). The code of `pairEqual` can use the interface of the `Eq` class for values of type `a` and `b` (i.e. it can test equality of `a` values, and can also test equality of `b` values).

But the important thing is that when multiple type variables are in use these choices and interfaces are completely independent of each other. The caller of `pairEqual` can choose the types `a` and `b` completely independently; it choose `a` to be `Char` and `b` to be `Maybe Bool` (by calling it as `pairEqual ('a', Just False) ('a', Nothing)`, for example). `a` and `b` don't have to have any relationship to each other.

And the code implementing `pairEqual` can call `==` on two `a` values to test whether one value of type `a` is equal to another value of type `a`, and it can do the same with `b` values, but it has *no* ability to test whether an `a` value is equal to a `b` value. The two `Eq` interfaces it has access to are independent from one another.

So this is quite different in effect from if we had `pairEqual :: Eq a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> Bool`. Here there's only *one* type variable for the caller to choose; both elements of both pairs have to be the same type. This gives more freedom to the code implementing `pairEqual`; it knows that both elements of both pairs are all of one single type and all work with the `Eq` interface it has. So it can test whether the first element of the first pair is equal to the second element of the second pair, if it wants. Our two-type-variable `pairEqual` from before couldn't do that. But it gives *less* freedom to people calling `pairEqual`; now `pairEqual ('a', Just False) ('a', Nothing)` is invalid, since there's no type that can be chosen for the single type variable `a` that allows the values `'a'` and `Just False`.

So using more or fewer type variables really depends on what you want to do. Using more can be "better" in that it gives more freedom to the callers of your function (i.e. it makes your function useful in more situations). The restrictions on the code of your function of using more independent types can also be useful for making sure you don't accidentally write the wrong code. But there usually just isn't a lot you can do with values of completely independent types, so you won't be able to just give every input value its own type variable.

Comment: Hello! Thank you SO much for your contribution, your explanation is both very rich and clear, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You could also define a type family that constrains every element of a list:

```hs
{-# Language DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint)

type
  AllCls :: (k -> Constraint) -> ([k] -> Constraint)
type family
  AllCls cls as where
  AllCls cls '[]    = ()
  AllCls cls (a:as) = (cls a, AllCls cls as)

allEqual :: AllCls Eq [a, b, c] => a -> a -> b -> b -> c -> c -> Bool
allEqual x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2 = and
  [ x1 == x2
  , y1 == y2
  , z1 == z2
  ]
```

Three can be implemented in terms of AllCls.

```hs
type Three :: (k -> Constraint) -> (k -> k -> k -> Constraint)
type Three cls a b c = AllCls cls '[a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a type synonym that lets you constrain a lot of types without having to repeat the constraint each time, like this:

```
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

type Three c t1 t2 t3 = (c t1, c t2, c t3) :: Constraint

allEqual :: Three Eq a b c => a -> a -> b -> b -> c -> c -> Bool
allEqual x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2 = x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && z1 == z2
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much! Is there any way to use raw Haskell syntax to write something similar?

Comment: @NickS1 What part of my answer do you not consider to be "raw Haskell syntax"?

Comment: @NickS1 `Data.Kind` is part of standard Haskell just as much as `stdio.h` is part of standard C. (Note that there are some modules that start with `Data.` that this isn't true of.)

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusion, what I really meant is: could this be done without importing any library?

I thought that using the Data library would sort of "increment things" in such a way that I wouldn't be able to do it without it, using no library at all.

Comment: @NickS1 `Data.Kind` is part of the same library that the Prelude is part of. Unless you're using the NoImplicitPrelude extension, you're not using "no library at all" (and even then, you're still using *some* stuff from `base`.)

Comment: If you want to partially apply Three you need the constraint synonym encoding: `class (c t1, c t2, c t3) => Three c t1 t2 t3` `instance (c t1, c t2, c t3) => Three c t1 t2 t3`

Comment: @NickS1 Importing modules **is** part of "raw Haskell", and an important part. For the most part, only basic tutorial exercises can be completed without importing anything; to write code that does anything practical you will need to get used to importing. It is true that installing optional libraries (and how to manage dependencies) is a topic that beginners should learn later, but there are quite a large number of modules that will come with any installation of GHC without any dependency management. You can and should use them, don't artificially limit yourself to the basic `Prelude`.